# adding a Simple tabhost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

### I have added a set of horizontal buttons on top of the tab

**but when i add these the tab is being merged along with the list as shown in the list below**

**As you can clearly see that tabs are merged with rows of a list**

**How can i prevent this ?**

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/screen_topbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**screen_topbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Move the `TabWidget` outside the `tabcontent` `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @ Luksprog ...Can you please edit the code as your answer.... Sorry i am a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `TabWidget` outside the `tabcontent` `FrameLayout` in the xml layout otherwise the tab content and the `TabWidget` itself will be in the same container and they will overlap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/screen_topbar" />

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```